# Google Docs Apps Script Loading Indicator

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running a script when I open/refresh a Google Doc. It takes some time to run and can affect values in the doc, so I want to show some type of loading indicator to the user until it's done. I would prefer to not overlay a modal, so the doc is still accessible, but apart from that any solution, even a hacky one, would be ok.

```js
// EXECUTE SCRIPT ON OPEN
function onOpen() {
  // SHOW LOADING TO USER
  initializeDoc();
  doSomeStuffThatTakesSomeTime();
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('MyMenu')
    .addItem('Click', 'doSomeStuffThatTakesSomeTime')
    .addToUi();
  // TURN LOADING OFF
}
```

Comment: From `I would prefer to not overlay a modal`, you want to achieve your goal without using a dialog. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You can use a `prompt` and just close it when needed. But since you said `I would prefer to not overlay a modal`, does that not serve as an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

#### Loading...

```
function loading() {
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Loading...."),"Please Wait");
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  const hl = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><script>window.onload=()=>{google.script.host.close();}</script><body></body></html>';
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(hl),"Good Bye")
}
```

You will require an installable onOpen() such as below:

```
function onMyOpen(e) {
  loading();
}
```

[image]

Comment: TIL about modeless dialog. Definitely what OP is looking.

Comment: @OctaviaSima TIL ?

Comment: Today I learned. Sorry for the unnecessary abbreviation.

Comment: @OctaviaSima That's okay.  I'm not a social media regular, so I often find myself lacking in the common vernacular.  I searched for it but perhaps not exhaustively

Comment: @Cooper thanks!! This is great. Can you explain 2 things: 1. Utilities.sleep functions as a timeout, is that because the dialog displays as a flash otherwise, or because in synchronous code it would execute `close` right away? (I ask because I'd like to replace the timeout with an actual trigger that operates before and after my code executes) and 2. What do you mean by "an installable onOpen()"?

Comment: An installable onOpen() is an function that is triggered by the onOpen() trigger but it is not named onOpen and it has the ability to perform operations that require permission.  Utilities.Sleep() is just a timeout.  There is no flash here as far as I know.  The Good Bye dialog is required to terminate the first dialog and then itself.